# Data is not deleted properly after running of Spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-datamapper

In my RSpec file, I have used FactoryGirl to create objects that I have used in my RSpec file. In my RSpec file I have used three objects `A`, `B` and `C`  where C is dependent on B and B is dependent on A. Here in RSpec file I have written two test cases: one for testing `index` method of my controller and another for `update` method. So I have created the objects which I have used to test those two methods, as follows:

```
before(:each) do
  @A = FactoryGirl.create(:A)
  @B = FactoryGirl.create(:B)
  @C = FactoryGirl.create(:C)
end
```

And here I am using test environment of Rails, so I am using corresponding test database which I have already. So to clean the database after running, I have written the following code:

```
 after(:each) do
   C.all.destroy
   B.all.destroy
   A.all.destroy
 end
```

But the problem is that after running the spec, while I am checking the tables corresponding to them I find that data is not deleted. Here I have used DataMapper in my models. So can please anyone help me to fix this problem i.e. to clean those tables after each run of spec. Thank you.

Comment: use transactional fixtures! (setting in your `spec_helper.rb` file). Or use database_cleaner for those pesky specs that require multiple threads (and thus can't use db transactions safely).

Answer (score 0):

You should use database cleaner gem, it helps you to run your specs in a transaction so your database is cleaned between each example. It also can be configured to run specific examples with deletion/truncation so you can use it with external tools (selenium or other drivers)

It's all explained right there:

https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner

Comment: But by reading it and from a few links from google I did not find how to use DataMapper with DataBase Cleaner gem, the articles mostly deal with ActiveRecord.